# HOw to get value from multiselect dropdown in flask python when method is get

Tags: python, html, flask

I am new to python/flask so need your help.
I have multiselect dropdown like below

I have a multiselect in html file like this:

```
<select multiple id="mymultiselect" name="mymultiselect">         
        <option value="1">India</option>       
        <option value="2">USA</option>       
        <option value="3">Japanthing</option>
</select>
```

as i have multiple button in form tag, and each tag point to different route, so instead of Post, I am using Get method.

But in Python wile not able to get the value from `request.args.get('mymultiselect')` , its getting none.

I tried `request.args.getlist('mymultiselect')` as well but no luck.

Could you please help me on same

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `request.forms.get("mymultiselect")` or `request.args.get()` ? I can't tell if you are posting or getting... but one of those should work. Don't forget the action= in your form as well.

Comment: Better show more of your code then? There is something else wrong. Need to see the <form> and probably the method in your Flask back-end code too

Answer (score 0):

```
request.args.getlist('mymultiselect')
```